# Set cast audio stream as default in system volume dialog

Tags: android, chromecast, android-audiomanager

I am trying to implement a UI button which will bring up the system volume control for the user while casting.

I have used the `AudioManager` for that, and specifically the call below:

```
audioManager.adjustSuggestedStreamVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME, AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

It does work, but the dialog that is brought up has the ringtone stream selected by default. The user has to expand the dialog and only then they can change the cast volume.

My question is - **is there an option to make the system volume dialog select the casting stream volume slider as the default one**? It must be possible, as this is what happens when I use the hardware buttons. But the question is if there is a public api for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me. I am not sure what are you missing. You can take a look at below sample app.

Test app: https://github.com/syatam/AudioTest

To verify the case:

1. Build and install above sample on your mobile
2. Cast video from your mobile using Youtube or any other app
3. Press home
4. Press volume button to make sure that the active control is chromecast
5. Now, open the sample app installed in first step
6. Click on "Volume Control" button and you should see active control as chromecast

FYI, I tested on Android N mobile.

Share your observations and device details, if you are unable to fix the issue.